# A word to describe the period from midnight to six in the morning

Tags: vocabulary

There's morning, noon, afternoon, evening and night.

Night is the period of time between the late afternoon and going to bed

Is there a word to describe the period between going to bed and waking up in the morning(or from mid-night to six in the morning).

I searched every corner of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn) without a satisfied word found.

Comment: First, you have the meanings wrong. Night is the time after the dusk that follows sunset, i.e. full dark, until the first light of dawn, which precedes sunrise. Evening is late afternoon until some time that most people would go to bed. The meaning of evening is somewhat fluid, and it can overlap the meaning of night. The meaning of night is more rigorous, but can be used in a less rigorous fashion and understood. There are sailing terms for the sections of the night (see Wikipedia: watch system), but they are not in general usage outside that discipline.

Comment: So, we have day, and night. Morning, midday, afternoon, and evening are common words that are used to break down night and day into smaller units. There are a number of phrases to describe the night hours, but they are more colorful, less common, and the exact time reference can vary depending on the speaker and context: "in the darkest hours", "the midnight hours", "oh-dark-hundred", and more. Faulkner uses the "first singing of the birds" to describe that time when morning dusk is imminent, as birds in the forest do begin song at that time.

Comment: Off topic but interesting: a new day or morning begins between 3;30 and 4 a.m. in Hinduism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are a variety of time periods:

> *early morning, before dawn, dawn, morning, late morning, noon (or midday), early afternoon, late afternoon, early evening, sunset, evening, late evening, dusk, twilight, night, late at night, past midnight, in the middle of the night*

plus any number of variations, colloquialism, and poetic expressions for each of these like:

> *lunchtime, bedtime, suppertime, the wee hours of the morning, when the cows come home,* etc.

The term to use for the time from midnight until dawn depends on what you are doing.  "Night" is sufficient if it is dark, but "early morning" can work if you are awake.  Some other examples:

- Expressions like *"the predawn hours"* depend on when the sun rises for that location and time of year, which in some cases can be very early.
- *"Past (my) bedtime"* is useful to express you are awake when you should be asleep, and can imply past midnight depending on the context.
- *"In the dead/dark/still of (the) night"* is a poetic expression that means "when it is very dark and most people are normally asleep, and everything is very quiet" -- which again can mean various times depending on location.
- *The witching hour* is a literary expression that means "exactly midnight", supposedly when witches come out to do what witches will do.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really as specifically as you're describing it here. I would say that "evening" is the time between late afternoon and going to bed, not "night." "Night" is usually while you're sleeping, although it could just refer to all the time when it is fully dark outside, whether you are sleeping or not (it's longer in winter, for example). The period between midnight and six in the morning is still "night" to most people. You could call it "early morning," too, since it's a.m. Some people who don't work traditional daytime hours or are up at odd hours for other reasons might make up their own words for all of these times of day, sometimes.

You could possibly say "my sleeping hours" if you want to be extremely specific about your personal "period between going to bed and waking up."